# Unknown Bike Frame

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

*EDIT: Someone in an FB group identified the bike as "Road Athlete".  Not sure if this is a brand or a model.  Unfortunately, the person who id the bike doesn't have much info either.  I was lucky we have the same bike.**

First time posting here.  Hope you can help me figure out the brand/frame of this bike.

I recently bought an old road bike that doesn't have any info on the frame other than a decal that reads RS21 in the head tube and seat tube.  There is also a remnant of an old decal where the tube shifters were located - it reads "RO" (it's the only part left).  The original owner probably failed to remove that piece.

The serial is located in the bridge of the chainstays and not underneath the BB.

Bike details:
RD - Shimano Skylark (has LH so it's probably around the 80's era)

FD - No model, only has Shimano logo

Shifters - Shimano tube shifters

Rims - Araya

Handlebar - Alps

Brake Lever - Yoshikawa 7 - F

[image: serial]

[image: whole bike]

[image: headtube decal]

[image]

[image: jis]

[image: rd]

[image: brake]

Comment: Welcome to the site - you've done an excellent job of taking photos, thank you.   Its definitely an 80s bike,    The location of the serial number is odd, that might be enough to trigger a memory from someone.

Comment: i wish all the 'id my bike' questions were this well written

Comment: Thank you kind sirs.. Someone ID the bike in an FB group (posted there too).  We have the same bike and the decals shows "Road Athlete".  I checked the internet but I didn't have any info.  Maybe someone can chime in some info if they know this brand/model.

Answer (score 1):

The "RS21" is a sticker, not a decal.  The subtle distinction is that anyone can whack a sticker on a thing, but a decal takes skill and effort to get right, and is often embedded under the clear-coat layer.   I see the sticker is slightly crooked, a suggestion it might not be original.

Shimano have a model of wheel with the code "RS21" so searching returns mostly those wheels, which is unhelpful.

There's a tiny chance the sticker says "RS211" as well - I see the white space between the 2 and 1 could be a second numeral 1.

---

No matter what - it looks like a good solid bike frame.  Simply change the brake pads.  Inspect the tyres closely and replace if perished.   Replace brake/shifter cables if they're rusty or not smooth-moving.

When you're done, get new decals made saying "Do Dela Rosa's Bike" and put them on the downtube, then clearcoat over and it will look authentic.

Comment: Thank you for the info and the tips.  You are right, it's a sticker and not a decal.  I have the same thoughts on getting it with new decals.  It's a good chromo frame.  The wheels were steel so I'm replacing that with alloy.